# Edited block is not display

Tags: bug

When I edit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614950/c-sharp-use-updated-dll-in-client-system#27614998) answer edited code is not display.[image: Snap shot].

To check I add `pre` tag when code wrapper is not work.Is there any thing I miss understanding for edit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's formatted in a code block (i.e., four spaces or forward-quotes), StackOverflow renders the post as HTML. Because of this, anything resembling an HTML tag (i.e., enclosed in angular brackets, `<>`, will not be displayed as text).

TL;DR - just indent the block four space by selecting it all and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, and you should be fine.